# "Windows fatal exception: access violation" error on Numba Python

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, numba

I am trying to use Numba `parallel` to parallelize a simple `for` loop. Surprisingly, I got a very strange error telling me this
`"Windows fatal exception: access violation"`.

Any idea what could be the issue?

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel =True)
def function(x):
    kk = []
    for i in prange(len(x)):
        kk.append([i, x[i]**10])
    return kk

b = np.random.rand(1000)

%timeit function(b)
```

Here's the whole line of errors I received:

```
Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374

Thread 0x00004548Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374

 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\garbage.py", line 49 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap


Main thread:
Thread 0x00001e38 (most recent call first):
  File "<magic-timeit>", line 1 in inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 169 in timeit
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 1180 in timeit
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\Kevin Yew\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232 in fun


Restarting kernel...
```